# Expand Parent Div to width of Elements with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, width, expand

I am currently developing a back end interface for a client of mine and i've hit a brick wall. It seems that Internet Explorer (all versions, including 9 beta) and Chrome are not displaying the page as desired. Firefox and Safari are displaying the page perfectly. I find it rather strange that it works on safari but not chrome.. anyway that's besides the point.

How the form looks in Safari and Firefox - it is the desired outcome:

[image]

How the form looks in all browsers other than Safari and Firefox - this is not desired:

[image]

I'm after a way to make the background expand to the width that is set in the css in these other browsers. Any hints and tips would be much appreciated as I've been stuck on this for about 5 hours today and it's starting to get very frustrating for me.

After some help, i've narrowed the problem down to the jQuery plugin "equal height columns" however I require the effect is has, so surely there is a way to make this work in the other browsers.

---

My HTML is:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User Login</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/reset.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="javascript/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="javascript/jquery.equalHeightColumns.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#form_left, #form_right, #form_right input").equalHeightColumns();

         });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <a href="forgot_password.html" class="loginmeta">Forgot Password?</a>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="header">
            <h1><a href="#">User Login</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div id="form">

            <form name="login" action="#" method="post">

                <div id="form_left">
                    <label for="">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" />

                    <label for="">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" />
                </div>

                <div id="form_right">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" />
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

            </form>

        </div>      

    </div>  

</body>
```

and the CSS:

```
//*
TYPE
*/
a.loginmeta                 { position: absolute; 
                          right: 20px; top: 20px; 
                          color: #4a4f5b; 
                          font-size: 12px; }
a.loginmeta:hover           { color: #5d6472; }

/*
    STRUCTURE   
*/
body                        { background:         url('../images/page_background.png') repeat; }
#container                  { width: 480px; display: block;
                          margin: 100px auto 0 auto; }

/*
    FORM
*/      

form                        { width: 480px; margin: 30px 0 15px     0; }

form label                  { color: #919191;
                          text-transform: uppercase;
                          display: block;
                          margin-bottom: 10px; }

form input                  { background: #ffffff;
                          border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
                          font-size: 17px;
                          color: #414141;
                          padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; 
                          width: 328px; }

#form_left, #form_right     { -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                          -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                          border-radius: 5px;
                          -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                          -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                          box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                           }

#form_left                  { float: left;
                          width: 350px; 
                          background: url('../images/form_background.png') repeat-x bottom left #f3f3f3;
                          padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px; }

#form_right                 { float: right;
                          background: url('../images/form_background.png') repeat-x bottom left #f3f3f3; padding-bottom: 30px; }

#form_right input           { width: 80px;
                          font-size: 12px;
                          text-transform: uppercase;
                          color: #939393;
                          background: none;
                          border: none;
                          margin: 15px 0;
                          padding: 0; }                           



***
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looks the same in IE8, FF3 and Chrome10 : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/FYGeZ/

Comment: thanks mate, I forgot to add that I'm using a jQuery plugin "Equal Height Columns" in the page - Ive added it to the code in the original post. With your help, I narrowed that plugin to be causing the problem in IE and Chrome. Grr so frustrating!

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug in FF to clarify that everything has the width and padding dimensions that your expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but since your problem seems to be coming from the plugin, maybe you could try this instead :

```
var columnMaxHeight = 0;
$("COLUMN_SELECTOR").each(function() {
    var columnHeight = $(this).height();
    if (columnMaxHeight < columnHeight) {
        columnMaxHeight = columnHeight;
        $(this).height(columnMaxHeight);
    }
});
```